# android with jddc with xampp

Tags: android, database, jdbc

I am trying to connect my android app with a xampp database on a localhost using
jdbc.error on the  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

the code :

```
   import java.sql.Connection; 
   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.*;

 public class conexionbase
  {
   private static final String url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.4:3306/proyecto";
   private static final String user="root";
   private static final String pass="";
      public conexionbase()
        {
          conectar();
        }
       public void  conectar()
      {

          try {
             //conecting with the database

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
               }

      catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();

    }  
}

   }
```

Comment: Did you add mysql connecter jar file?

Comment: i had this mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar

Comment: and this is on the build.gradle                                                                                             dependencies {

    compile files ('libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar')
}